# How to split an array in java or Kotlin?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, split

How can we split an array of objects? For example, I have a variety of chars like this:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

I want to split the array with the spaces seen in position 6. After breaking, the collection will look like this:

```
Array1 = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
Array2 = ['W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

I did find a post something like this over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3181368/17133283), but that is not in java or Kotlin.

I know I could have done it this way:

```java
String str = TextUtils.join(",", arr);

String[] splittedString = str.split(" ");
```

But, I want another way if it is possible. Using this `.split` method takes up a lot of memory and about 30-40 milliseconds on large arrays.

How can I do this with java or Kotlin?

Comment: If the original array contains characters only, then you could just join the original array into a string, split it by space and then split the parts again into their characters. It remains unclear what the actual use case is and what the return type of a split method should be (`List<List<Char>>`?)

Comment: Good choice. But, I have at least a 5000 elements in my array. Converting and splitting will surely take some time @Stuck

Comment: 500 is no problem. You could optimize the count of iterations but you will always need to look at each element making it `O(n) `. I would consider the performance only if it is a problem (might be the case if the method is executed very often)

Comment: What is `0(n) ` @Stuck. And oops. it is abt 5000 not 500

Comment: 5000 is no problem. `O(n)` google big o notation.

Comment: Can't the array just be joined into a string, split on space, then back to arrays ? how did you come with that initial array ? Can't more logic be done before reaching to that strange array ?

Comment: @azro I dont want that way. I could have done it that way already. But, I was looking for some easy short way for it

Comment: @Stuck now that the post is reopened, you can post an answer for that as I dont have idea about  google big o notation

Comment: an array is a very raw structure, very few things can be done on it, so there will no short solutoin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is joining the original array into a string, split by space and then split again into the characters (here in kotlin):

```kotlin
arr.joinToString().split(" ").map{ it.split() }
```

This is not optimized but still in `O(n)` (linear complexity). It benefits from readability which most often should be preferred whereas performance should be addressed if this is critical to your task at hand.

Comment: what is that split the second time?

Comment: the first split separates the joined string by space which results in array -parts that contain multiple characters. The second split then splits those parts again into the characters.

Comment: Try `joinToString` then. I updated the answer.

Comment: this one does not seem to work. The previous one was doing the job. This given me an error in the IDE. [See this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJtv9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did it in Java for fun. Not very concise though. I cant seem to be able to do it using Streams properly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] chars = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
        char[][] char2d;

        String[] tokens = String.valueOf(chars).split(" ");
        char2d = new char[tokens.length][];
        for (int i=0; i< tokens.length; i++) {
            char2d[i] = tokens[i].toCharArray();
        }

        for (int i=0; i< char2d.length; i++){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(char2d[i]));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
[H, e, l, l, o]
[W, o, r, l, d]
```

Managed to replicate it with streams as follows:

```
char[][] char2d2 = Arrays.stream(tokens).map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);
for (int i=0; i< char2d2.length; i++){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(char2d2[i]));
}
```

Gives the same output as above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume a generic array with elements that does have a proper implementation of `Object::equals`; for a mere array of `char`, the suggested solutions based on the String operations are the most effective implementations.

Try this:

```java
final Element [] input = …
final Element split = …
final List<Element[]> output = new ArrayList<>();

var start = 0;
var end = 0;
while( end < input.length )
{
  if( input [end].equals( split ) )
  {
    output.add( Arrays.copyOfRange( input( start, end ) ) );
    start = end + 1;
  }
  ++end;
}
if( start < end ) output.add( Arrays.copyOfRange( input( start, end ) ) );
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit weird. It uses java somewhere and Kotlin somewhere. Also, my IDE is complaining about that

Comment: @Sambhav.K – I am using pure Java, but Java 17 …

Comment: Oh. I am not aware of java 17. I though that var and val are in ktx. Not in java. So, was a bit confused. And, those 3 dots in a row in the top 3 lines if u see, what are those? I have only seen them in method params

Comment: @Sambhav.K – Oh, the ellipsis in my code sample … they are just indicating that I was to lazy to provide a sample for the array to split, and for the element that marks the "split" (in the sample with the character, this was the blank).

Comment: that split is `space -> ' '` right?

Comment: @Sambhav.K – As said in my answer, I assume an array with a generic type, where the only requirement is that this type provides a proper implementation of `Object::equals`. This also means that you can translate the solution easily to work for an array of `char`, too. But as I said, too, for such an array, the solutions based on String operations are sufficiently effective.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get u good. Can u pls edit your post?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with just an extra ArrayList and StringBuilder, no converting the whole input to a String.

```
String[] splitOnSpaces(char[] chars) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ) {
        while (i < chars.length && chars[i] == ' ') {
            ++i;
        }
        while (i < chars.length && chars[i] != ' ') {
            word.append(chars[i++]);
        }
        if (word.length() > 0) {
            strings.add(word.toString());
            word.setLength(0);
        }
    }
    return strings.toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

It could be even more concise if you allow single statements to be on the same line as `if` or `while` statements.

```
String[] splitOnSpaces(char[] chars) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ) {
        while (i < chars.length && chars[i] == ' ') ++i;
        while (i < chars.length && chars[i] != ' ') word.append(chars[i++]);
        if (word.length() > 0) strings.add(word.toString());
        word.setLength(0);
    }
    return strings.toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Converting the array to a String and splitting it in Java:

```
    final String[] array = { "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d" };
    final String[] arr = String.join("", array).split(" ");
    final String[] subArray1 = arr[0].split("");
    final String[] subArray2 = arr[1].split("");
```