# How to split an array of objects in java or Kotlin?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I have already asked one question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72283809/17133283) but, that answers about only strings. I could not edit that as there a couple of answers there already.

---

Now, I get it how to split it with a space as given in that post. But, how can I split it with objects of custom class like this:

```java
public class User{
   private boolean isAdult = false;
   private int age = 0;

   @Override
   public String toString(){
      return "User : { isAdult = " + isAdult + "        age = " + age + "}"
   }

   // getters and setters
}
```

Now, I want to split on places where `isAdult` is false. For example I have this array:

```
[User : { isAdult = true         age = 19}, User : { isAdult = false         age = 10}, User : { isAdult = true         age = 38}, User : { isAdult = false         age = 17}, User : { isAdult = true         age = 19}]
```

Now, on splitting of `isAdult` to being false, it will be like this:

```
Array1 = [User : { isAdult = true         age = 19}]
Array2 = [User : { isAdult = true         age = 38}]
Array3 = [User : { isAdult = true         age = 19}]
```

So, how can I achieve this in java or Kotlin

Comment: i suppose you could try modify ```input [end].equals( split )``` to ```input [end].isAdult == false```? from the solution provided by @tquadrat

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I didn't understand that answer. He uses java somewhere and Kotlin somewhere. That is weird

Comment: Is splitting really what you want? What's your use case? It seems to me that you simple want to filter a list of users to adult ones. And this doesn't involve any splitting

Comment: @IvoBeckers uh. It is kind a filtering. But, also, we can see that it gets seperated in different arrays when a `isAdult` user comes false. And, TBH I dont have any use case for it and wouldn't bother a lot if this isn't answered. Just asked in curiosity.

Comment: fyi, i have expanded my kotlin answer a bit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on tquadrat's answer (in Java):

```
public static class User{
        boolean isFalse;
        int value;

        public User(boolean b, int v){
            this.isFalse = b;
            this.value = v;
        }

        public String toString() { return "User("+this.isFalse+", "+this.value+")"; }
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        User[] users = {new User(true, 5), new User(true, 1),new User(false, 7),
                new User(true, 10), new User(false, 3)};
        ArrayList<User[]> output = new ArrayList<>();

        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        while( end < users.length )
        {
            if( users[end].isFalse == false)
            {
                output.add( Arrays.copyOfRange( users, start, end  ));
                start = end + 1;
            }
            ++end;
        }
        if( start < end ) output.add( Arrays.copyOfRange( users, start, end ));

        for (User[] arr: output){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }

    }
```

Giving output:

```
[User(true, 5), User(true, 1)]
[User(true, 10)]
```

Comment: There are empty arrays for consecutive falses, so you may want to look out for those. FYI

Answer (score 1):

This is a kotlin answer

It wasn't entirely clear to me but assuming you are working with an array of `User` objects, this function will return an array of arrays with each a single user that is adult:

```
fun convert(array : Array<User>) : Array<Array<User>> =
    array.filter { it.isAdult }.map { arrayOf(it) }.toTypedArray()
```

EDIT:

judging from the accepted answer you want it grouped together for consecutive users that are adult, here's a full working program in kotlin demonstrating it. `convert` does without the grouping, `convert2` with:

```
data class User(var isAdult : Boolean, var age: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "User : { isAdult = $isAdult        age = $age}"
    }
}

fun main() {
    val users = arrayOf(
        User(true, 3),
        User(true, 5),
        User(false, 6),
        User(true, 7),
        User(false, 9),
        User(true, 11)
    )

    for (array in convert(users)) {
        println(array.contentToString())
    }
    println("==============")
    for (array in convert2(users)) {
        println(array.contentToString())
    }
}

fun convert(array : Array<User>) : Array<Array<User>> =
    array.filter { it.isAdult }.map { arrayOf(it) }.toTypedArray()

fun convert2(array : Array<User>) : Array<Array<User>> =
    array.fold(arrayOf(arrayOf())) { result, user ->
        if (user.isAdult) {
            result.copyOf(result.lastIndex).filterNotNull().toTypedArray() + (result.last() + user)
        } else result + arrayOf<User>()
    }
```

output:

```
[User : { isAdult = true        age = 3}]
[User : { isAdult = true        age = 5}]
[User : { isAdult = true        age = 7}]
[User : { isAdult = true        age = 11}]
==============
[User : { isAdult = true        age = 3}, User : { isAdult = true        age = 5}]
[User : { isAdult = true        age = 7}]
[User : { isAdult = true        age = 11}]
```